# Laravel relationship returning null when tryying to fetch type using foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch the type of user using the foreign key in the users table i.e. `user_types_id` but when I do it I just get `null` and cant get into the function `userType` in `User Model`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance. I have provided related models and tables

***Controller***

```
public function dashboard() {

    $userType = UserType::all();

    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    var_dump($id); // returns id

    $users = User::find($id);
    var_dump($user->user_types_id);  // returns user_type_id in users table

        if($users->userType){
            var_dump($users->userType->types); // error is in here. Not taking userType.
        } else {
            echo 'does not exit';
        }

        die();

    return view('dashboard', compact('users'));
}
```

***User Model***

```
    <?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use App\UserType;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        /**
          * The attributes that are mass assignable.
          *
          * @var array
          */

        protected $fillable = [
            'username', 'password',
        ];

        /**
          * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
          *
          * @var array
          */

        protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
         ];

        public function userType() {
            return $this->belongsTo(UserType::class);
        }
    }
```

***UserType Model***

```
    <?php

    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\User;

    class UserType extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable=['types'];

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
        }
    }
```

***User Table***

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_types_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('salt');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

***UserType Table***

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('types');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've named your relation **userType**, therefore **Eloquent** assumes that the foreign key is called **user_type_id**, not **user_types_id**.

Replace

```
return $this->belongsTo(UserType::class);
```

with

```
return $this->belongsTo(UserType::class, 'user_types_id');
```

to tell **Eloquent** the name of foreign key column and it should work.

Comment: it did work for me ... thank you so much for the help ... :) oh okay ... my bad ...

Comment: Eloquent makes a couple of assumptions about key names if you don't provide them explicitely. It assumes that primary key is called "id", it also derives foreign keys from relation names.

Comment: ya I got it ... there shouldn't be that "s" in the foreign key ... that was so stupid mistake from my side but thank you ... :)